# Reflection on type members?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, scala-generics

I know this is possible:

```
import scala.reflect._

trait Foo[A]

def isDouble[A: ClassTag](foo: Foo[A]) = classTag[A].runtimeClass == classOf[Double]

object Foo1 extends Foo[Double]
object Foo2 extends Foo[String]
assert(isDouble(Foo1))
assert(!isDouble(Foo2))
```

But, now I want to make the `A` an abstract type:

```
import scala.reflect._

trait Foo {
  type A
}

def isDouble(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???

object Foo1 extends Foo {override type A = Double}
object Foo2 extends Foo {override type A = String}
assert(isDouble(Foo1))
assert(!isDouble(Foo2))
```

How do I implement the `isDouble` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala let's you refer the arguments to the left of a curried function (in this case `foo`):

```
def isDouble(foo: Foo)(implicit ev: ClassTag[foo.A]) = classTag[foo.A].runtimeClass == classOf[Double]
```